# Three.js Cannot find Obj

Tags: three.js

I am using the file from three.js and used the OBJloader and render with canvas. Except that I cannot find the object even when I scale the object by 1000 and set the camera to 2. The code is as below.

```
<script src="../mrdoob/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="../mrdoob/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="../mrdoob/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="../mrdoob/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script>
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
init();
animate();
function init() {
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth /     window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
//camera.position.z = 100;
camera.position.z = 2;
// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101030);
scene.add(ambient);
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 1);
scene.add(directionalLight);

                    // texture

                    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
                    manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {

                        console.log(item, loaded, total);

                    };

                    var texture = new THREE.Texture();

                    var onProgress = function (xhr) {
                        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
                        }
                    };

                    var onError = function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr);
                    };

                    alert("hi");

                    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
                    loader.load('../mrdoob/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg', function (image) {
                        texture.image = image;
                        texture.needsUpdate = true;

                    });

                    // model
                    alert("hi2");
                    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    loader.load('../mrdoob/examples/obj/male02/male02.obj', function (object) {

                        object.scale = new THREE.Vector3(1000, 1000, 1000);
                        alert(object.position.y);
                        scene.add(object);
                    });



                    //
                    alert("hi3");

                    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                    renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

                    //

                    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
                    alert("hi4");

                }

                function onWindowResize() {

                    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

                }

                function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

                    mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 2;
                    mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 2;

                }

                //

                function animate() {

                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    render();

                }

                function render() {

                    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
                    camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;

                    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

                    renderer.render(scene, camera);

                }

    </script>
```

I did an alert on the object and the position turns out to be zero, so I am not sure if the object is correctly loaded. If someone can tell me how to look for the object would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may cause if the camera located inside your object, then it always see the back faces of your object and ignore it.

Please provide jsfiddle live example.

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle example. This is the only working example, http://jsfiddle.net/5hcDs/22/ All of my attempts to load from the the obj file seems to fail as well since I cannot find a working obj loader from jsfiddle. My question would be, how to convert an .obj 3d model to a javascript variable so I can parse it with loader.parse?

Comment: Try working in your local, means copy all javascript and assest files to your local folder and using local server (for example, mongoose) to load the html file. then you can insert code just after loader load the obj file and save it in json file. this file is an object that you can embed in the jsFiddle version.

Comment: Even the example webgl loader is not working. I'll try converting the file to JSON and load it in with a json loader. If that does not work than I am out of ideas. The canvas example is working though.

Comment: the jsfiddle from your first comment work on my laptop. so maybe you have HW problem... the examples from three.js website is working on your machine?

Comment: The webgl_loader_obj is not working, I tried rendering it with canvas, does not show up either. My laptop is a bit outdated, what kind of HW do I need?

Comment: Hi, I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651797/loading-obj-model-from-local-machine-with-three-js, turns out I never ran it with Firefox. Thanks for your help.